# ASP Access Database web site on Windows 2008 Server running IIS 7

Tags: ms-access, iis-7, asp-classic, permissions, windows-server-2008

I am upgrading my server to Windows 2008 Server from IIS 6 running Windows 2003.

I am not sure what permissions and what account is needed to access the Access database.

In Windows 2003 I had given Write permission to the IUSR account, what it the equivalent in Windows 2008?

The database is not in the web site folder.

I am getting a 500 - Internal server error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under IIS7 this isn't really any different.  Although user account is simply IUSR (or more accurately "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR") there is no machine name suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little snippet of ASP to see what the anonymous user's name is:

```
<% 
Response.Write Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") 
' or 
Response.Write Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER") 
%>
```

Also, if all you see is "500 - Internal Server Error" you need to configure IE to give you more details instead of the "friendly" error message, or use another browser.

Comment: I tried these and it is not writing anything, they are blank. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Those will be blank unless you're using one of the Windows authentication mechanisms.